# How to evaluate a expression in java which contains powers (2^3^5)

Tags: java, pseudocode

I have implemented a console calculator in java, which gets a expression then converts it to postfix then evaluates and prints the result.

But I have a problem when I input expressions which contain two powers next to each other (2^3^5 etc.). It converts to `23^5^` as a postfix expression, but should convert `35^2^`, because for powers it has to start from right.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using stack for operators, taking into account their precedences !

Answer (score 2):

Exponential operator has right to left associativity. It needs to be evaluated in depth first manner.  This [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#A_detailed_example) explains in detail on how to handle it.

Comment: Ok thanks it seems that I should append parentheses. It could be!

Comment: @bantik No. There are no parentheses in postfix notation. This is just evading the issue. You might have parenthess in the *infix:* you are supposd to be getting rid of them, i.e. *implementing* them, not introducing them for someone else to implement. The parentheses in the citation are just there to express the precedence which is implicit in the parse tree.

Comment: @bantik I don't understand why anyone would suggest something that they knew to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It should actually convert to 235^^.

Comment: Could be! But if you use stack for operators you will get 35^2^ . Why? The first element(2) is a number so it goes into String postfix, then  next element(^) is an operator, so it should be pushed into the stack, then 3 appends to the postfix, the next ^ when comes the topStack should be poped and appended to the postfix string.

Comment: @bantik I don't. I get 235^^. Operands appear in postfix in the same order they did in the infix. Operator precedence and associativity are expressed by where the operators are. 1+2*3 becomes 123*+, 1*2+3 becomes 12*3+. 2^3^5 becomes 23^5^ if left-associative, or 235^^ if right-associative.

Comment: @bantik I also note that your description of the process doesn't agree with your output. If 3 is appended to the postfix string after 2, how did 2 get to be after 3? You need to review your code to agree properly with that (correct) description, and to produce the outputs I have given here for the corresponding inputs.